# Google analytics how to find Active Users by host name

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

We've got an web based enterprise application which has GA hooked into it. Previously i've just been viewing the active user count to see what our count is across the board. Im wanting to get the figure of Active Users via Host Name, which would think would be an easy figure to pull out of google analytics but apparently not. Just wanting to see if anyone has any ideas of getting this figure. So would be something like:

- CompanyA.com.au - 26 Active Users (1 day active)
- CompanyB.com - 15 Active Users (1 day active)
- CompanyC.org - 7 Active Users (1 day active)
- etc etc

Comment: I often create views that filter by hostnames. Sometimes that can be a neat way to do it. The new views do not get historical data and you would have to set up things like goals separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom report to get this information.

[image]

1. Go to "Customization".
2. Select "Custom Report".
3. Title your report "Users by hostname".
4. Add the Metric Group "Users" (I also added "Sessions" and "Pageviews" to my report).
5. Add the Dimension Drilldown of "Hostname".
6. Save your custom report.

When you view this new custom report you will get the statistic you want:

[image]

The time period will be for the dates given by the report.  If you want 1 day active users, change the time period to just yesterday.  For seven day active users, change the time period to the previous seven days, etc.

[image]

If you still have Abode Flash working in your web browser you can use the "motion charts" feature in Google Analytics to graph users per day over time for each subdomain.   See [Graphing the performance of sub-domains in Google Analytics](https://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/)  However, Flash is no longer supported and I can't get it to work in Chrome in Google Analytics anymore.

Comment: If you have Flash installed, you should  be able to get Flash to work for the motion charts using Chrome. If you log into GA, click the padlock in the browser address bar and it should show Flash being blocked by default, and you can change the setting to allow Flash for the analytics.google.com domain

Comment: @BronwynV thanks.  That should work for a few months.  Google is removing flash entirely from Chrome in January: https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap

Comment: I won't be sad to see it go re the flash. I'm surprised the motion charts are still even in GA (most newer GA users do not even know of their existence).

Comment: I use them only for creating line graphs with multiple lines on them.   That seems like it should be a first class feature, not hidden under "motion charts and not relying on out-of-date technology.